# MyBB {} Tags displaying instead of interpreting

Tags: php, templates, theming, mybb

I've been editing my MyBB portal.php, and up until recently it was displaying fine. I had added a custom welcome block above the recent posts, and it was displaying fine.

Today I went in to tidy up the code, adding new lines (enter) and indents to make the code more legible. Now, after doing this something went badly wrong. Instead of showing the full MyBB page styles, all it shows is the tags like {$header}. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{$mybb->settings['bbname']}</title>
{$headerinclude}
</head>
<body>
{$header}
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" border="0" align="center">
<tr><td valign="top" width="200">
{$welcome}
{$pms}
{$search}
{$stats}
{$whosonline}
{$latestthreads}
</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="top">
<table border="0" cellspacing="{$theme['borderwidth']}" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" class="tborder">
    <tr>
        <td class="trow1">
            <span class="smalltext">
<!--Main Welcome Panel-->
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            <img alt="" src="http://axelcraft.net/images/welcome.png" style="width: 1024px;" /></p>
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            <span style="color:#696969;"><span style="font-size: 24px;"><em><span style="font-family: hutrmold;">Get ready for a whole new minecraft experience.</span></em></span></span></p>
<!--Slideshow-->
<center>
    <iframe src="http://axelcraft.net/images/slides/slideshow.html" width="800" height="320" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" style="overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
</center>
<!--End Slideshow-->
        <p style="text-align: center;">
            <span style="font-size:20px;">
                <span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    Thanks for visiting AxelCraft! Start by <a href="http://axelcraft.net/member.php?action=register"><span style="color:#385947;"><span style="">signing up</span></span></a> to get the latest news and updates on the server as well as to register for <a href="http://axelcraft.net/forumdisplay.php?fid=9"><span style="color:#385947;">contests</span></a> and <a href="http://axelcraft.net/forumdisplay.php?fid=19"><span style="color:#385947;">events</span></a>!
                </span>
            </span>
        </p>
<!--End Welcome Panel-->
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
{$announcements}
</td>
</tr>
</table>
{$footer}
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when you navigate to portal.php, it only shows the {$} tags along with the html paragraph. It's supposed to be showing sidebars and headers left and right like MyBB does. See what I mean [here.](http://axelcraft.net/portal.php)

Compare that to the normal forum page [here](http://axelcraft.net).

I can't figure out what's wrong or why it's not displaying properly.

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong but are you missing an '>' here

```
<tr><td

<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" border="0" align="center">
<tr><td valign="top" width="200">
```